# COBOL Compilation issue (linked to C program)

Tags: c, fortran, cobol, cobol85

There were some 10 COBOL modules linked to 4 fortran modules. I converted the fortran codes to C programs. And linked the 10 cobol modules to the replacing 4 C modules.

In these 10 COBOL modules, there should be "ENTER C" statements replacing ENTER FORTRAN statements now. And after that while compiling, I found that two of these COBOL modules - throw error while compiling. Other don't.

The error I get is this: "Arithmetic expression too complex: Floating point used!" - and it points to similar lines in these COBOL modules. (I compiled using COBOL85)

The lines where the errors are pointed out, looks somewhat like this: 
COMPUTE D = L OF E / (( L + (A/100)) ** ( Z OF J(S-1)/365))
Here, the L,E,A,Z & J are possibly coming from the C program.

There were other lines pointed out too, that looks somewhat similar. Most common of those lines were the ** (exponential operator).

Note: These 10 COBOL modules compiled fine when linked with those fortran modules, so I'm to believe that the problem is with the equivalent C program that was written. Also I used the following changes in my C module when converting from FORTRAN.

INTEGER*8 to long int in C.
DOUBLE PRECISION to DOUBLE in C.
INTEGER to int in C.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: I'd use `long long int` for an 8-byte integer. But its platform dependent, check to see if `long int` is 8-bytes on your platform.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Is it not compiler dependent?

Comment: that is correct, both platform and compiler dependent.

Comment: What are L, A and Z - are they integers or doubles?

Comment: They are actually just integers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit too unorthodox to answer my own question, but I just found the reason for the 'warnings' and I've cleared them. So for anyone else coming here with a similar warning, here's the answer.

That compute line was just too complex for COBOL85 compiler to handle. I split up the equation into small bits and then put them together and they worked like a charm!

So there goes! No data type issues, or anything at all, actually! Thanks for all those who tried to help, btw. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: There is nothing at all unorthodox about answering your own question. If you find the answer yourself, this is the correct way to do it. Note that not many COBOL's have `ENTER` at all. In this COBOL it does not seem to be used to the Standard, and I think it is now Obsolete anyway. When you next visit, you should include the name of the COBOL you were using.